# Como passar um array php como paramentro do $.ajax data?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Como passar um array php como paramentro do $.ajax data?
Ex:

```
<?php $nomes = array('maria','joao','jose'); ?>

  $.ajax({
    url: 'pagina.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {'nomes' : <?php echo json_encode($nomes); ?>},
    sucesss: function(data){
      console.log(data);
           }
     });
```

E na pagina pegar esse array.

Comment: Esse código para mim não faz sentido nenhum. .-.

Comment: Use `$variável = json_decode($_POST['nomes']);`, dessa forma você terá $variável[1], $variável[2], $variável[0].

Comment: A forma como está fazendo está correta...explique melhor sua dúvida

Comment: Bem, pelo o que eu percebi, pelo fato do array em php não conter keys a função json_encode o converte para um array javascript normal. Então no caso talvez minha pergunta deveria ser como converter esse array js para um array php ao pega-lo com $_POST na pagina de destino. Obrigado pelas respostas.

Comment: Eu não acho legal esse negócio de misturar código jquery com php, isso é gambiarra². Transforma o array em json, depois escreve ele dentro de um elemento HTML. capture o valor do elemento via jquery e o esconda. Agora não tenho como formalizar uma resposta, quando eu chegar em casa eu tento postar

Comment: Vlw pela resposta Adriano, tbm não gosto fazer dessa maneira, por isso postei a pergunta aqui, vou tentar sua dica. Abr.

Answer (score -2):

```html
nomes = [];
nomes[0] = 'maria';
nomes[1] = 'joao';
nomes[2] = 'josé';


$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: {nomes :nomes},
   url: "pagina.php",
   success: function(msg){
     console.log(data);
   }
});
```

Comment: bem vindo ao SOPT, sempre é interessante explicar o que seu código faz, assim melhora o entendimento da solução do problema